# Primitive Idempotents

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of diameter $n$ and $\theta_0,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n$ the distinct eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of $G$. The following was defined as the primitive idempotents of $A$ (the adjacency matrix of $G$): For $0\leq i\leq d$,
$$E_i=\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{A-\theta_j I}{\theta_i-\theta_j}$$.

What is the motivation for defining the $E_i$'s in this manner?

Comment: Did you want to put the tag [tag:algebraic-graph-theory] instead of (algebraic)?

Comment: @Martin: I've edited to algebraic-graph-theory, but I suspect the OP may have wanted to create an [algebraic-combinatorics] tag.

Comment: @Willie We will see what the OP says.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't graph theory but linear algebra: the $E_i$ are the projections onto the eigenspaces of $A$ (which I assume is the adjacency matrix). You can prove this by looking at what each $E_i$ does to the eigenvectors of $A$; the argument is essentially the same observation that powers Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: I see. This works with any square matrix $A$ (not necessarily the adjacency matrix of some graph).

Comment: You need the condition that the eigenvalues are distinct or else the denominator is not well-defined.

Comment: The matrix $A$ had better be at least diagonal too, or the $E_i$'s need not be idempotent.

Comment: @Chris: you mean diagonalizable? This is implied by having distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: I meant diagonalizable. But you do not need $A$ to have distinct eigenvalues.